# Is there any benefit to declare a constant in a local scope in C#?

Tags: c#, constants

Is there any benefit to declare a local variable as "const" if I know that I won't be chaning its value?

Thanks,

Comment: Is there any benefit to declare constant as variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would usually use a const throughout your entire solution.  But the benefits for using in a local scope, would be that you know some place else in your scope you won't be changing it. And also if someone else is working on this code, they will know not to change it as well.
This makes your program more maintainable, because you need to maintain only the const (even if its just in a local scope)

Answer (score 5):

Declaring the variable const will also allow the compiler to do optimisation - instead of say allocating an int on the stack and placing its value there, the compiler may just use the value directly with your code

ie The following:

```
const int test = 4;
DoSomething(test);
```

Could be compiled as

```
DoSomething(4);
```

by the compiler

**Edit:** Reply to "constant propagation" as the comments box has size limit

Using ildasm to check betweeen const and none const for release with optimisation:

The code

```
int test = 4;
Console.WriteLine(test*2);
```

Compiles to

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       11 (0xb)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] int32 test)
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4.4
  IL_0001:  stloc.0
  IL_0002:  ldloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0004:  mul
  IL_0005:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_000a:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

While

```
const int test = 4;
Console.WriteLine(test*2);
```

gets optimised to

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       7 (0x7)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4.8
  IL_0001:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_0006:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

This is using 2010 in release with optimisations.

I did a search to learn more about constant propagation and while posible, the current compiler doesn't do this as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163995.aspx)

Comment: Even if you don't tag your variable as const, the optimizer will easily determine that your variable is a constant and then will produce the above code. It's called "constant propagation".

Comment: @Roubachof I'd not heard of "constant propagation" before, thanks for the comment. I've edited my answer with a link I found while reading up about it; it turns out the current compiler doesn't do it - maybe in the future! (Once they've fixed the current bugs in 2010!)

Comment: really ?? this is a so basic optimization technic i'm really amazed by this news. Good job!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You will protect your code from accidentally changing this variable.

Answer (score 3):

I like to do this when I'm passing a boolean flag indicator to a method:

```
const bool includeFoo = true;
int result = bar.Compute(10, includeFoo);
```

This is more readable for me than a simple true/false, which requires reading the method declaration to determine the meaning.

Comment: I like this Dan.  I've noticed that MS seem to do this in their source code:

base.Compute(10, true /* includeFoo */);

which has the benefit of remaining one line.

Comment: In C# 4.0, you can use named parameters to accomplish the same thing (hopefully the parameters have sensible names!) Not what they were introduced for, but they have the advantage of ensuring you use the correct names (using either const locals or comments in a call with many such flags might get them accidentally muddled).

Comment: When I design my own interfaces, I tend now to try to avoid boolean parameters in the first place and either create different public methods that map to an internal method with a flag or use enum values for the flag.  I still find this technique helpful when interoperating with APIs that take a boolean or 'magic' parameters (like string.Empty to indicate 'missing').

Answer (score 2):

Declaring the local as const will let the compiler know you intention so you won't be able to change the value of your variable elsewhere in your function.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the valid answers, not only do you tell the compiler that the value won't be changing, you quickly tell anyone else that will be looking at your code.

Comment: I declare local consts for other programmers more than any other reason.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on case of use..

For example,

```
void Foo()
{
    const string xpath = "//pattern/node";

    new XmlDocument().SelectNodes(xpath);
}
```

in this case I think const declaration is meaningless

Comment: I think this still has value, one reason being for consistency. If you always use the local scope const rule, you are less likely to forget it in a spot where it may be more beneficial (your not loosing anything here by using it, and its not a lot of extra typing anyways). Also, if this function were to grow larger in the future, you need not worry about someone changing the value further in the scope without realizing your initial intent.